# What does "hold over" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, verbs, phrasal-verbs

This context comes from the video game "Divinity Original Sin II"

In the game, two people are going through an exorcism in order to banish a spirit inhabiting one of them. This is the beginning of the dialogue that depicts the process.

"They begin to hum in unison, a low, rumbling note **held over** several out-breaths"

**"hold over"**

2. verb To temporarily defer or delay something. In this usage, a noun or pronoun can be used between "hold" and "over."
   *Hold that project over until I'm able to get some questions answered by the boss.* (source: Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. © 2022 Farlex)

Or maybe it's not the phrasal verb but two separate words which mean:

**"hold"**

a. The sustaining of a note longer than its indicated time value.
(source: American Heritage® Dictionary)

&

**"over"**

3. during; through, or throughout (a period of time)
   (source: Collins English Dictionary)

Comment: It's not a phrasal verb, but two separate words, as you guessed.

Comment: It's two words, and roughly means, "a low, rumbling note *which continues during* several out-breaths"